# Swift 3 Table View - Remove Stack View from some cells

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, stackview

I've got table view cells which contain, amongst other things, a stack view. The stack view should only be in a cell, if some requirements are true. If not, then the height of the cell should be reduced.
When I use .isHidden, the height stays the same. But I want the stack view to be removed from that cell.

Here's my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RumCell", for: indexPath) as! RumCell

    let currentRum: Rum
    currentRum = rumList[indexPath.row]

    cell.rum = currentRum

    if (cell.rum?.clubRatingJuicy == 0) && (cell.rum?.clubRatingGasy == 0) && (cell.rum?.clubRatingSpicy == 0) && (cell.rum?.clubRatingSweet == 0) {
        cell.frame.size.height -= 76
    }

    return cell
}
```

As you can see, I tried to reduce the cell height, but this doesn't work. I also tried this, which doesn't work:

```
    if (cell.rum?.clubRatingJuicy == 0) && (cell.rum?.clubRatingGasy == 0) && (cell.rum?.clubRatingSpicy == 0) && (cell.rum?.clubRatingSweet == 0) {
        cell.tastStack.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Can you try to add `self.tableView.beginUpdates()`and `self.tableView.endUpdates()` after you remove the stack view and calculate your new height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use different cell prototypes `RumCell` (without stackview) and `RumCellDetailed` (with stackview) which both conform to a protocol `RumCellProtocol` (where you can set the `rum` var)

```
protocol RumCellProtocol {
    func config(rum: Rum)
}
```

and this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cellIdentifier = "RumCellDetailed"

    if (cell.rum?.clubRatingJuicy == 0) && (cell.rum?.clubRatingGasy == 0) && (cell.rum?.clubRatingSpicy == 0) && (cell.rum?.clubRatingSweet == 0) {
        cellIdentifier = "RumCell"
    }


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RumCellProtocol

    let currentRum: Rum
    currentRum = rumList[indexPath.row]

    cell.config(rum: currentRum)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code for dynamic height, and Give constraint without fix height in tableView cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 100.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting cell frames.  That's not how TableViews work.  If the cell heights are dynamic then @Theorist is correct.  If not, you can implement

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:     NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath), let rum  = cell.rum, rum.clubRatingJuicy == 0 && rum.clubRatingGasy == 0 && rum.clubRatingSpicy == 0 && rum.clubRatingSweet == 0 {
    return {no stackview height} //whatever the height should be for no stackview
}
    return {normal height} //whatever your value is
}
```